# Boost, после установки отсутствуют библиотеки

Tags: linux, boost

Добрый день,

устанавил boost 1.65.1, часть библиотек отсутствует (например boost.asio или boost.lambda).
Как устанавливал :

- Скачал `boost_1_65_1.tar.gz`, распаковал, где следует
- Место для самого буста приготовил, далее `~/ExtLibs/boost_1_65_1/`
- В месте распаковки запустил `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=~/ExtLibs/boost_1_65_1/`
- Далее `./b2 install`
- Подождал, а захожу в папку `~/ExtraLibraries/boost_1_65_1/lib`, а там половины библиотек нету, зато вот в include всё есть.

Подскажите, как исправить сей недуг, как доустанавливать.

P.S. Скрин в описании
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чего именно не хватает? на мой взгляд всё на месте...

Comment: ldconfig не пробовали?

Comment: @Hellseher  
Разве в папке lib не должно быть файлов типа liboost_asio*? Idconfig, это что?

Comment: Скрин сделан мобильником что ли? О_о

Comment: `libboost-all-dev` ставить не пробовал?